# (x86) returns "undefined reference to printf" when compiling to an executable

Tags: compiler-errors, x86, nasm

I'm writing a simple hello world program, but when I compile it to a .exe, it return this:

```
hello.obj: In function `start':
hello.asm:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `printf'
```

These are the commands I'm using:

```
nasm -f elf32 hello.asm -o hello.obj
ld -m i386pe -o hello.exe hello.obj
```

and this is my code:

```
extern _printf

section .text

global _start

_start:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    push msg
    call _printf
    add esp, 4

    leave
    ret

section .data
    msg     db  "Hello, world!", 13, 10, 0
```

My file and the nasm files are in CodeBlocks\mingw\bin

I tried putting the underscores in front of the externs, like in C, but it still returned the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "My file and the nasm files are in CodeBlocks\mingw\bin" - No! That's where CodeBlocks itself goes. Put _your_ files in _your_ directory.

Comment: You didn't tell the linker to link any libraries that provide an implementation of `printf`, so it didn't.  There should be a libc somewhere, or as Microsoft calls it a "C Runtime" library aka CRT.  The one from MSVC is I think called msvcrt, so there should be a DLL of that on your system already somewhere (since lots of Windows programs use it.)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually written `_printf`. You just promised to supply that function when you wrote `extern _printf`.

Comment: how would I do that, do I need to get a c script and paste it in the same folder?

Comment: @Chromegism: A C "script" isn't a real thing. You might be able to find a Standard C *library* with `printf` included, compatible with your OS.

Comment: printf is included in C, so why would I need an external library to use it. Also, how do I import printf to x86 as I was only told to just get one. Nothing I've tried has worked.

Comment: @Chromegism: `printf` is included in C, yes. You're writing assembly, not C. And I've got no idea what you mean with "import printf to x86". You need a Standard C library that's compatible with your OS. x86 is relevant, but Linux-x86 is entirely different from Windows-x86.